# Adding buttons in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, button, highcharts, draggable, qualtrics

I have inserted a highchart graph in qualtrics for a question I wanted to ask. Respondents answer the question by dragging the line.
I wanted to add a button to reset the values of the line to the initial values I showed them as default, or to show them specific values.
Here are the html elements of the question

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px">&nbsp;</div>
<button id="button">Set new data</button>
```

Whereas here is the js

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()

{
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    animation: false
},

legend: {
        enabled: false
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3']
},
yAxis: {
        min: -2,
        max: 10,
        tickInterval: 2,
        lineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: '\% points'

        },

},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {

                drag: function (e) {
                    // Returning false stops the drag and drops. Example:
                    /*
                    if (e.newY > 300) {
                        this.y = 300;
                        return false;
                    }
                    */

                    j('#drag').html(''
                        'Dragging <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' +  Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y,2)  + '\% </b>');                 
                },
                drop: function () {
                    j('#drop').html('' 
                        this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat((Math.ceil(this.y*20)/20),2) + '\% </b>');
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals:2
        },
        stickyTracking: true,
        getExtremesFromAll: true,
        marker: {
                radius: 6
        }

    },

   /* line: {
        cursor: 'ns-resize'
    }*/
},

tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
},

series: [{
    data: [0, 0, 0],
    dragMinY:-2,
    dragMaxY:10,
    draggableY: true,
    cursor: 'ns-resize'

}],
});
j('#button1').click(function () {
        chart.series[0].setData([5, 6, 2] );
});
j('#button2').click(function () {
        chart.series[0].setData([0, 0, 0]);
    });
});
```

(Notice that, since Jquery(preloaded in the header) conflicts with prototype I reset the $ to j to prevent conflicts).

Now, the buttons should work, they should do what they are meant to, but something is odd: if I click on the graph to drag the line, the first button is automatically clicked, and I do not understand why. If I click the second both are clicked. What's worst, every time I click the page reloads. This is specific to Qualtrics only, I tried to implement this in jfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tg35u440/) and everything seemed to be fine.
So, do you know what I actually have to do to prevent qualtrics from reloading the oage everytime a button is clicked on? And why are the buttons creating a conflict with the dragging function on screen in Qualtrics?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be fine, are you able to replicate your issue there? Have you tried to run a console (developer tools in chrome) and check that some errors appear?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on your earlier Highcharts question (I also mentioned the https issue), the Highcharts code is using $ to refer to jQuery (search the Highcharts js code for "$("). That is likely the cause of your problem.